# Detecting a remote WCF service contract change

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to be able to tell if a WCF service has been updated and that I need to update my service reference.

For example, I can receive objects from the remote service that are of type `ShapeBase`. From when I last updated my service reference, it pulled a known type descendent of `Square`.

But, if on the remote service they now introduce a new descendent of `ShapeBase`, say `Circle`, then my code continues to work until they send a `Circle` object down, at which point it all falls in a heap trying to deserialize (not surprisingly).

Is there a programatic way of validating the contracts between what I have locally and what is on the remote service? I would just like to know if there is a discrepancy as early as possible.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ShapeBase", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.WCF.Shapes")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Shapes.ServiceReferences.Shapes.Square))]
public partial class ShapeBase : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Square", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Test.WCF.Shapes")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class Square : Shapes.ServiceReferences.Shapes.StructsBase
{
}
```

Comment: Normally servicer providers won't make such changes without prior notice to their consumers. There is always a notice period and prior intimation about what will be changed, how it will impact existing consumers along with remedies to avoid serious breaks. So there is no direct way you can detect changes of service unless service providers release that information by some or the other way. So all in all you should not expext such breaking changes in service at least in production environment.

Comment: Thanks, but this has already happened to us. There's also the possibility that someone is notified but it gets missed, so I'd like to build in some sort of daily validation check and raise an alert if it's at all possible to do in code.

Comment: What you can do at the best is have automation test running periodically which will trigger an alarm if it fails. That would not tell you what changes are made at the service side but you can investigate and figure out if its service problem or client problem and take necessary action. But there is no way you can figure out what is changed at the service end until the service providers tells. If you are facing this issue in production environment then it's a serious issue you need to take it up with the service provider.

Comment: Again even after notifying, if you miss to update the client then service provider is not at fault.

Comment: Manually, I could compare the generated code before and after updating the service reference. I was hoping that something could be done in code, even if it's a little crude. Unfortunately, the automation test idea is only going to tell me at the same time as it fails for real, but the contract change could have been made months before.

Comment: That's why you need to be vigilant about the service updates and notification from the provider. If you fail to notice that and update your code accordingly you have no way out but to face failure. Imagine if Google or Amazon changed their services like this without notifying their million dollar customers. They notify and do pre-release months before the actual release or release a new version of service without impacting current version customers.